# Binding caps lock to escape in z-shell

Tags: zsh, vi

I want to rebind the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to escape in z-shell to make better use of the vi-mode in the z-shell line editor. I don't want to rebind it for the entire system.

edit:
I'm currently running on debian. I use zsh with and without X-server.

Is there any solution that is independent of the underlying linux-distribution?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in http://www.superuser.com/

Comment: Second @SampritiPanda's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sampriti Panda and BK201 pointed out the question doesn't belong here and I reposted it on superuser.com. The question is solved now, to see the solution follow this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/709616/binding-caps-lock-to-escape-in-z-shell).